# Itterate to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to iterate over this array in order to take all league values (`league_id`,`name`,`type` etc)

```
array:1 [▼
"api" => array:2 [▼
"results" => 970
"leagues" => array:970 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "league_id" => 1
    "name" => "World Cup"
    "type" => "Cup"
    "country" => "World"
    "country_code" => null
    "season" => 2018
    "season_start" => "2018-06-14"
    "season_end" => "2018-07-15"
    "logo" => "https://media.api-football.com/leagues/1.png"
    "flag" => null
    "standings" => 1
    "is_current" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:13 [▼
    "league_id" => 2
    "name" => "Premier League"
    "type" => "League"
    "country" => "England"
    "country_code" => "GB"
    "season" => 2018
    "season_start" => "2018-08-10"
    "season_end" => "2019-05-12"
    "logo" => "https://media.api-football.com/leagues/2.png"
    "flag" => "https://media.api-football.com/flags/gb.svg"
    "standings" => 1
    "is_current" => 0
  ]
  .......
```

but until now,with the following code:

```
$request = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
foreach ($request as $array=>$val) {
   foreach ($val['leagues'] as $id) {
        dd($id);
   }
}
```

the only thing that i can get is the first array only and not the rest:

```
array:13 [▼
"league_id" => 1
"name" => "World Cup"
"type" => "Cup"
"country" => "World"
"country_code" => null
"season" => 2018
"season_start" => "2018-06-14"
"season_end" => "2018-07-15"
"logo" => "https://media.api-football.com/leagues/1.png"
"flag" => null
"standings" => 1
"is_current" => 1
]
```

any help?

Comment: you are calling `dd`, dump and die, so you are killing the script after the **first** iteration of that loop, so you are only accessing the first element of that array ... if you just want to dump data without killing the execution you can use `dump($var)` instead

Comment: Did you mean to do this instead: `foreach ($request['leagues'] as $league) { print_r($league); }`. Also if you use `dd()` it means `die and dump`, i.e. it will print the contents of the variable and then exit, so that;s probably why you are getting only the first item?

Answer (score 3):

The `dd()` function you are calling is killing the execution of your script on your first iteration.

From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd):

> The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script.
>
> *If you do not want to halt the execution of your script, use the dump function instead.*

Just iterate over it like so:

```
$request = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
foreach ($request['leagues'] as $id=>$league) {
  print_r(compact('id', 'league')); // To see the id and value array
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: remove the `dd`

Comment: didn't realize what `dd()` was. Thanks,